# Excel: How to remove duplicates and create new structure

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple data in Excel like so:

[Original Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCNjx.png)

And new to restructure that to something like this:

[Result Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajpOc.png)

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot table would definitely be the way to go. Below is a link with the steps to setting one up.

https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2013/pivottables/1/